# Spring Integration inbound-gateway reply-channel has no subscribers for channel

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a trivial "Hello World" example workflow here where I want to expose an `inbound-gateway` web service that responds in plain text. I believe the way I route the response to `myReplyChannel` is incorrect.

```
<int:channel id="myRequestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="myReplyChannel"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway id="myGateway"
                          path="/hi"
                          supported-methods="GET"
                          request-channel="myRequestChannel"
                          reply-channel="myReplyChannel"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="myRequestChannel"
                 output-channel="myReplyChannel"
                 expression="'Hello World!'"/>
```

This works when deployed, but when I first call the service I see this logged:

```
Adding {bridge:null} as a subscriber to the 'myReplyChannel' channel
Channel 'org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext:myReplyChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
started org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer@4eef7503
```

Looks like Spring is adding in a subscriber for `myReplyChannel` at the last minute. I'd prefer to do it correctly myself.

**Unit Test**

I wrote a simple unit test to debug this..

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:hello.xml" })
public class HelloWorldTest {

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel myRequestChannel;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        myRequestChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("").build());
    }

}
```

This errors out with:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException:
  Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel
'org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@64485a47.myReplyChannel'.
```

This reads to me like my configuration is wrong and here Spring isn't holding my hand.

**Alternative Configuration:**

I've tried just dropping `myReplyChannel` all together and it worked without anything in the logs.

```
<int:channel id="myRequestChannel"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway id="myGateway"
                          path="/ok"
                          supported-methods="GET"
                          request-channel="myRequestChannel"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="myRequestChannel" expression="'OK'"/>
```

Is this the correct setup? If so, what is the `reply-channel` parameter for?

With this configuration, I get the following error in my unit test:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException:
  org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException:
    no output-channel or replyChannel header available
```

Answer (score 0):

> Adding {bridge:null} as a subscriber to the 'myReplyChannel' channel

.

> debug this

There's nothing to "debug". This is just a DEBUG message from framework internals. Each request gets a dedicated `replyChannel`header. Typically, you don't need a `reply-channel` on the gateway; the framework will automatically route to this request's reply channel header when it arrives at some component that has no `output-channel` (as you have found in your second test).

If you **do** specify a reply channel, the gateway creates a bridge internally so that any reply specifically sent there is bridged to the request's replyChannel header.

Typically, the only reason to ever specify a reply-channel is if you want do do something else with the reply (e.g. wire tap the channel to log the reply, or make the channel a publish-subscribe channel so you can send a copy of the reply somewhere else).

Your tests are failing because you are not populating the replyChannel header like the gateway does.

If you want to emulate the HTTP gateway in your test code, use a messaging gateway, or simply use a `MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive()` - either one will correctly set up the replyChannel header in the request message.

Alternatively, use:

```
    myRequestChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("")
                             .setReplyChannel(new QueueChannel())
                             .build());
```

Each request needs its own reply channel header so we know how to route the reply to the right requesting thread.